# How to change "val" values in an object without changing the definition to "var"?

Tags: arrays, json, kotlin, gson, data-class

I have a complex Kotlin data class, say something like this:

```
data class Post(
    val message: Message,
    val dateAndTime: LocalTime,
    val postAuthor: Author?,
    val visitorsVisitedTimes: List<Pair<LocalTime, Author>>
)
```

and each of `Message, LocalTime, ...` are different data classes.

I have an object of above `Post` data class. I want to parse it, access `visitorsVisitedTimes` field value, for each pair, replace `Author` object with corresponding `postAuthor`. I have to make similar changes in the `Message` object as well.

And I don't want to make changes in the class definition.

One way would be to convert this object into a json string, parse it, make require changes and cast it back to `Post::class.java` and return it.

I did something like this:

```
// input is an object of Post::class
var jsonString: String = Gson().toJson(input)
// parse the json string, make required changes
var objectFromJson: Post = Gson().fromJson(jsonString, Post::class.java)
return objectFromJson
```

But, I'm not sure how to make required changes in the Json string.

How can I do that, if not, is there any other way to do the task?

Comment: Is it okay to create new instances of the data class? Because then you could use the `copy` function, only changing the properties you need to change (via named arguments).

Comment: Do you need to modify existing object or create a copy with modified data?

Comment: @Slaw there is no necessasity for me to return the same object. In the final object I return, the data should be as expected.

Comment: @broot there is no necessasity for me to return the same object. In the final object I return, the data should be as expected

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a copy of an object, see https://kotlinlang.org/docs/data-classes.html.

```
val newPost = post.copy(
    message = post.message.copy(text = "some text"),
    postAuthor = Author(...)
)
```